# PEP8 between specific lines

Tags: python, django, pep8

I have some huge files in my codebase which have many pep8 related issues.

Is there any way to analyze specific lines with pep8

```
pep8 input /path/to/my-code.py --lines=100-200
```

So that I can analyze specific part of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in feature in pep8 for this, but you can achieve this by combining pep8 with a terminal tool such as sed:

```
sed -n '100,200p' /path/to/my-code.py | pep8 input -
```

In this case the output of sed (line 100 to line 200 of your file) is used as the input of pep8